# Spacing issues with Superfish Two Column Menu

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, superfish

I've been working on my non-profit's website, trying to fit our loooong dropdown menus into two columns with little success. I've widened the UL and set the width of the LI items to 50%, but I am getting large white gaps on longer items. The tutorials I've seen have a much simpler structure and I'm left scratching my head.

Here's a Jfiddle that will hopefully shed some light: 
http://jsfiddle.net/iota/7EHnE/

|Edit: updated for a little more clarity|

Thanks!
Nick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix your problem by setting the `background-color` on the `ul` instead of the `li`s.